# javascript / jquery - select the larger of two numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, comparison, comparison-operators

I'm trying to use javascript to select the greater of two numbers. I know I can write an if statement, but I'm wondering if there's some sort of Math operation or something to make this more efficient. Here's how I'd do it with an if statement:

```
if (a > b) {
    c = a;
}  
else {
    c = b;
}
```

Comment: `c = a > b ? a : b;`, `max(a,b)`?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You're looking for the Max function I think....

```
var c = Math.max(a, b);
```

This function will take more than two parameters as well:

```
console.log(Math.max(4,76,92,3,4,12,9));
//outputs 92
```

If you have a array of arbitrary length to run through max, you can use `apply`...

```
var arrayOfNumbers = [4,76,92,3,4,12,9];
console.log(Math.max.apply(null, arrayOfNumbers));
//outputs 92
```

OR if you're using ES2015+ you can use spread syntax:

```
var arrayOfNumbers = [4,76,92,3,4,12,9];
console.log(Math.max(...arrayOfNumbers);
//outputs 92
```

Answer (score 15):

```
c = (a > b) ? a : b;
```

This will do the same thing. This can be really useful and a real time saver.

Comment: The parentheses can be omitted