# What is the javascript shorthand for this?

Tags: javascript

```
if(pf[i].length > highest){
    highest = pf[i].length;
}
```

What is the most efficient way of conveying the statement above?

Comment: Do you mean most concise? readable ? Because it would be hard to beat that in terms of computational efficiency

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript / jquery - select the larger of two numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424721/javascript-jquery-select-the-larger-of-two-numbers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Math.max` function returns the largest of zero or *more* numbers.

```
highest = Math.max(pf[i].length, highest)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would the largest of zero mean? and what would you use that for?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) : "If no arguments are given, the result is -Infinity". That may be useful when comparing the result of one Math.max invocation to another. Or when you the number of args is only known at runtime and may be zero

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Math.max` to get the maximum of the two values, `highest` and `pf[i].length`.

```
highest = Math.max(highest, pf[i].length);
```

Or, you can also use ternary operator.

```
highest = pf[i].length > highest ? pf[i].length : highest;
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                          Condition
//                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^           Execute when True
//                                                ^^^^^^^ Execute when False
```

The value from Ternary operation is returned and is set to the variable `highest`.

Comment: While the accepted answer is correct, this one contains it too, plus it adds a faster alternative - using the ternary operator. Ran a performance check on both and the latter is faster. Here are my results:  
**Math.max** - 163,350,669 ops/sec
**higher ? higher : lower** - 209,320,719 ops/sec  
That is a **28% performance improvement**.

Answer (score 1):

Try inline IF statement (ternary operator):

```
highest = pf[i].length > highest ? pf[i].length : highest;
```

Comment: Called a ternary. Also, wouldn't this undesirably overwrite  `highest` with an empty string in the false case?  I suggest `...: highest;`